# Django incude url not working

Tags: python, django

Here is the base url :

```
url(r'^api/v1/accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
```

In accounts.urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^signup/?$', signup, name="ref_singup"),
    url(r'^login/?$', user_login, name="ref_login"),
    url(r'^logout/?$', user_logout, name="ref_logout"),
```

)

http://localhost:8000/api/v1/accounts/logout

responds with `404`.

```
Using the URLconf defined in accounts.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^signup/?$ [name='ref_singup']
^login/?$ [name='ref_login']
^logout/?$ [name='ref_logout']
```

Feeling lost here: )

**Update**
After fixing the ROOT_URLCONF , Still getting 404

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/?next=/api/v1/accounts/logout
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^api/v1/accounts/
The current URL, accounts/login/, didn't match any of these.
```

I'm making the request for /api/v1/acounts/login/ but above it showing as /accounts/login/  ?

Comment: What is the result of `reverse("ref_logout")`? (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)

Comment: And the value of [ROOT_URLCONF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/ref/settings/#root-urlconf)?

Comment: Seems like it is treating accounts.urls as the base urlconf. Have you done anything to change `settings.ROOT_URLCONF`?

Comment: 'accounts.urls' i have fixed it to 'mysite.urls' for base url

Comment: That is your issue, it should point to the URLConf where you `include` `accounts.urls`.

Comment: Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^api/v1/accounts/
The current URL, accounts/login/, didn't match any of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Django is redirecting you to the default login url, most likely because of a `login_required` or `user_passes_test` decorator.

Obviously, your login url is not `/accounts/login/`, so you'll need to set or change your `LOGIN_URL` setting to point to `/api/v1/accounts/login/`. If you don't want a redirect at all, you'll have to change the `user_logout` view.

While you're at it, you probably want to set `LOGOUT_URL` and `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` as well.

Comment: Btw, I would never use a pattern ending in `/?`, but instead use `APPEND_SLASH = True`(the default) and `CommonMiddleware`. This ensures that there is a single, canonical url, while the url without a slash still works (by redirecting to the url with a slash).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `views.` before your url views:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^signup/?$', views.signup, name="ref_singup"),
    url(r'^login/?$', views.user_login, name="ref_login"),
    url(r'^logout/?$', views.user_logout, name="ref_logout"),
)
```